# Execute script on content page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am making an extension for one website and on specific pages there is a button that executes logic that I need to trigger from extension. Lets say page has button `<button onclick="page_action('1')">Click me</button>`. `page_action` function is located in separate file that is hosted in CDN, for example `https://website.cdn.com/my_script.js` and this `my_script.js` is defined on websites page (`head tag`).

So my question is how and if its even possible to manually execute `page_action` from within chrome extension ?

Finding and clicking button element isn't an option cause in some cases this button is hidden.

Tried different variations and one error that I stumbled was related to CSP. This code is even throwing error:

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://website.cdn.com; object-src 'self'"
  }
```

Comment: Send a click event: document.querySelector('button').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))

Comment: @wOxxOm It would work if the button would be present on page but there are special cases when that button is not rendered and thus no item to dispatch event.

Comment: Ah, it seems like `page_action` is a global function in which case you can do it in a script element, [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Thanks for the idea @wOxxOm but Method 2/3 give me following error:
`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.`

I'm not sure its issue on my side or its blocked by the content page itself.

Comment: As the answer says, only method 1 is compatible with ManifestV3.

Comment: Yeah. Missed that part, my bad. Now experimenting with Method 1.